# Matplotlib, multiple line plots axis annotation

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, plot, axis

I have five points with multiple `x(t)`, `y(t)` and `z(t)` coordinates that I want to plot using matplotlib in one figure. I've wrote this python code:

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    fig = plt.figure(4)
    fig.set_facecolor('white')
    yprops = dict(rotation=0,
                 horizontalalignment='right',
                 verticalalignment='center')

    axprops = dict(yticks=[])
    targets = ['centroid_label','centroid_base','centroid_apex','midgland_inferior','midgland_left','midgland_right','midgland_superior']

    count = 0.0
    axlist = []
    for target in targets:
        x,y,z = getXYZMotion_with_compensation(case,target)
        ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, count, 0.8, 0.2], **axprops)
        axlist.append(ax)
        axprops['sharex'] = ax
        axprops['sharey'] = ax
        ax.plot(list_of_times_in_minutes, x)
        ax.plot(list_of_times_in_minutes, y)
        ax.plot(list_of_times_in_minutes, z)
        ax.set_ylabel(target, **yprops)
        count = count + 0.2

    #turn off x ticklabels for all but the lower axes
    for ax in axlist:
      plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)

    plt.show()
```

which produces:

[image]

However, I want to have x axis description for all axis below the lowest graph and y axis description for every sub-figure from -3 to 3. How can I achieve that?

Comment: I don't fully understand how exactly do You want it to look. Can You try to explain it better or maybe give us a sketch or some picture.

Comment: Also it would be easier to help You if You could provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we could run Your code and try to fix it.